# How do I prevent layouts from pushing up when soft keyboard is shown in mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to have a fixed image in the background that does not move when the soft keyboard is shown. Every time I trigger the soft keyboard,
the whole image scrunches up. How do I prevent that ?

This is the css-in-js for my image.

```
width: '400px',
    position: 'absolute',
    height: 'auto',
    top: '0',
    left: '0',
    right: '0',
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    bottom: '0',
    margin: 'auto',
    zIndex: '1',
    maxWidth: '100vw',
    minHeight: '100vh',
    maxHeight: '100vh',
    cursor: 'pointer'
```